# Storing (redirecting) a looped-function print to a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have two python scripts, one of which is calling a function in the other:

First (first.py):

```
def get_values(number):

   ....

   for x in range(number):
        print x
```

Second (second.py):

```
import first

....

data = first.get_values(10)
```

My goal is to save the output from *get_value* in *first.py* to save to the variable *data* as a list (i.e. [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]). Is there any possible way to do this, without printing these values in the process?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I can't alter *first.py*, due to other functions already relying on it's current output.

Comment: So is the print function the only output of first.py?

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone Yes it is. The script first.py was originally used for a another purpose (it's stdout was being piped to another script's stdin), but I'm trying to recycle it so I can use it with second.py in this example. Which is why I can't alter first.py to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect your output to an io stream and then read that afterward (Python 3.5).

```
import sys
import io
stdout = sys.stdout  # keep a handle on the real standard output
local_i = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = local_i  # Choose a file-like object to write to
for i in range(10): # this is just an example, you have to call your function here from first.py
    print(i)
sys.stdout = stdout# revert to standard output

print("This printing is after the function call. You can process it as you want. This is just for demonstration purpose.")

for i in local_i.getvalue():
    if i != '\n':
        print(int(i))
```

For Python 2:

```
import sys
import StringIO
stdout = sys.stdout  # keep a handle on the real standard output
local_i = StringIO.StringIO()
sys.stdout = local_i  # Choose a file-like object to write to
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
sys.stdout = stdout# revert to standard output

print(
    "This printing is after the function call. You can process it as you want. This is just for demonstration purpose")

for i in local_i.getvalue():
    if i != '\n':
        print(int(i))
```

Output:

```
This printing is after the function call. You can process it as you want. This is just for demonstration purpose.
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 -- is this still valid?

Comment: @Jeff yes but you have to change two lines of code as iostream is different in 2 and 3. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can grab stdout using [redirect_stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import io
# if python3
# from contextlib import redirect_stdout
# if python2
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

# Note: I took this method from someone else's SO answer, but I think
#       they took it from someone else...etc.
@contextmanager
def redirect_stdout(new_target):
    old_target, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, new_target # replace sys.stdout
    try:
        yield new_target # run some code with the replaced stdout
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old_target # restore to the previous value

def get_values(number):
    values = tuple(range(number))
    for v in values:
        print(v)
    return values


def main():
    saved_stdout = io.StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(saved_stdout):
        data = get_values(4)
    print(data)

    data = get_values(2)
    print(data)


main()
```

Output:

```
$ python stdout.py 
(0, 1, 2, 3)
0
1
(0, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In first.py create a list like:

```
def get_values(number):
    ....
    return [x for x in range(number)]
```

then in second.py you can do

```
data = first.get_values(10)
```

Comment: you forgot `range()`

Comment: I should've added this as well; I'm not allowed to alter first.py in any way.